# Consumo estranho de memoria PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, querybuilder

Tudo bom pessoal,

Estou usando Laravel para um projeto e estou meio preocupado com o uso de memoria em algumas classes.
Então resolvi fazer um teste básico e descobrir que um método estava consumindo muita memoria e resolvi mudar algumas coisas...entre elas substituir o uso do Elouquent pelo QueryBuilder.

Veja:

Antes:

```
    $grade_blocos = \App\Blocos::where('grades_id', '=', $grades_id)
                            ->with(['produtos' => function($query) {
                                    $query->select('id');
                                }])->orderBy('bloco', 'asc')->orderBy('dia_semana', 'asc')
->get()->toArray();
```

Depois:

```
$select = 
                [
                    'blocos.grades_id',
                    'blocos.bloco',
                    'blocos.dia_semana',
                    'blocos.duracao',
                    'blocos_produtos.blocos_id',
                    'blocos_produtos.produtos_id',
                ];

        $grade_blocos = DB::table('blocos')
                ->join('blocos_produtos', 'blocos.id', '=', 'blocos_produtos.blocos_id')
                ->select($select)
                ->where('blocos.grades_id', $grades_id)
                ->get();
```

Com isso eu ganhei alguns megas e alguns milissegundos.

Mas daqui para baixo não houve alteração no método.

O estranho que o que foi economizado acima não refletiu no final gastando mais abaixo.

Eu fiz alguns teste em partes interessantes do código vejam resultado:
Observe as tarefas "Consulta Blocos" e "Consulta Comerciais"

Realmente eu não entendi porque a consulta ao banco da tabela comerciais começou a consumir mais memoria depois que alterei de deixei a consulta  blocos mais leve, levando em conta que não alterei a consulta comerciais.

Sem alteração:

> ```
>     Laço While
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 0.00536 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 9.25 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 9.5 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 0.25 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     **Consulta banco de dados tabela "Blocos"
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 0.57876 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 9.5 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 39.25 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 29.75 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------**
>
>     Consulta banco de dados tabela "Comerciais"
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 0.53618 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 39.25 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 50.5 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 11.25 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     Laço Foreach Final
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 2.60831 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 50.5 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 52 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 1.5 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     TEMPO TOTAL DE EXECUÇÃO DO SCRIPT
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 3.72881 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 9.25 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 52 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 42.75 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
> ```

Com alteração:

> ```
>     Laço While
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 0.00576 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 9.25 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 9.5 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 0.25 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     Consulta banco de dados tabela "Blocos"
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 0.0788 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 9.5 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 18.75 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 9.25 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     Consulta banco de dados tabela "Comerciais"
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 0.54036 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 18.75 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 49 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 30.25 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     Laço Foreach Final
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 2.20804 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 49 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 50.25 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 1.25 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>
>     TEMPO TOTAL DE EXECUÇÃO DO SCRIPT
>     -----------------------------------------------------
>     Tempo de execução: 2.83315 s.
>     Memoria inicial: 9.25 MB.
>     Memoria Final: 50.25 MB.
>     Memoria Utilizada: 41 MB.
>     -----------------------------------------------------
> ```

O que pode está acontecendo ?

Comment: Na primeira versão você pega todos os blocos, e depois executa uma query para cada um pegando os respectivos produtos. A segunda versão tem um join, portanto só traz os blocos que possuem produtos. São diferentes.

Comment: Além disso, o segundo não tem order by, o que pode influir muito no tempo de execução da query.

Comment: @bfavaretto:
Sim por isso resolvi usar join (mesmo alguns dizendo para usar Elouquent).
Mas o problema é que a quantidade de memoria gasta na tabela comerciais, sendo que essa não foi alterada.

Comment: @bfavaretto:

Essa query é executada nos dois casos e estão gastando memoria de maneira diferente.

$blocos_tempo = DB::table('comerciais')
                ->join('produtos', 'comerciais.produtos_id', '=', 'produtos.id')
                ->select('blocos_id', 'atividades_comerciais_id', 'data', 'produtos.duracao')
                ->whereIn('blocos_id', $blocos)
                ->where('data', '>=', $periodo_inicio)
                ->where('data', '<=', $periodo_fim)
                ->get();

Comment: Já acho absurdo um Framework que consome 9mb de memória só pra executar um `Hello, world`, enquanto uma página PHP normal `Hello, world` gasta em média 270kb ... Agora imagina o absurdo que é ~40mb para um servidor por requisição. O problema do Laravel é que ele vive de "buffer", fora que o middleware dele percorre por várias coisas, ou seja qualquer coisa nele vira um devorador e ele não é o único framework a passar por isto, a maioria dos populares passa, claro que não vou ficar aqui indicando frameworks bons vs ruins, creio que de pra melhorar muito no laravel se ajustar teu código.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento

Então Guilherme... estou tendo isso, mas não estou entendo porque um trecho do método passou a gastar mais sem modificação, somente porque no trecho anterior eu consegui economizar.

Comment: @bfavaretto "Na primeira versão você pega todos os blocos, e depois executa uma query para cada um pegando os respectivos produtos." na verdade ele pega todos os blocos e produtos pela relação, ele executa na verdade 2 `SQL` e se houver produtos repetidos nos outros blocos ele coloca a classe da mesma instância. Esse em relação ao de baixo é mais rápido mesmo tendo 2 `orderBy`, claro que deve levar muito em conta como está configurado as tabelas.

Comment: @DanielLopes as duas formas executam `Query Builder` e na versão mais atual foi igualado tanto para `Eloquent` tanto para `DB`, faltou dizer uma coisa quantos registros são retornados na primeira, inclusive os da relação? e quantos são retornados na segunda com `inner join`? fiquei curioso.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Vou verificar aqui...mas o que mais me impressiona é porque o código que vem **após** o este código modificado... 

Observe esta parte: **Consulta banco de dados tabela "Comerciais"**